# Переполнение стека в сборке. Пытаюсь найти решение

Tags: c#

Всем добрый день!
Есть вот такая строка. Нужно вставить строку между фигурными скобками, если эти скобки относиться к методу
Судя по коду видно, что я хочу найти рекурсивные функции и посчитать их вызовы, что бы они не переполнили стек

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        int stackCount = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = @"using System;
 
namespace HelloWorld
{
     class Program 
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(""Hello World!234""); // Hello World
             Foo();
        }
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(""Hello World!234""); // Hello World
             Foo();
        }
        static void Foo()
        {
            Foo();
        }
    }
}
";
            string insertStr = "stackCount++;if(stackCount > 1500) throw new Exception()";
            Regex regex = new Regex("\\s.?/*");
            MatchCollection match = regex.Matches(str);
            foreach (var item in match)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых у вас строка похожа на код, который не скомпилируется, не может быть 2 одинаковых метода в коде. Во-вторых есть Roslyn API, которая занимается как раз анализом C# кода. Регулярки здесь ни к чему вообще. И я так и не понял, что делает этот код. Во всяком случае, он никак не относитася к тому что вы над ним написали.

Comment: @aepot похоже он хочет написать свой анализатор

Comment: Бесполезно писать код для поиска рекурсий на коленке. Т.к. примитивные рекурсии вы и так глазами увидите, а вызовы рекурсивных методов с условиями и параметрами - тут вам регулярки мало помогут.